# How do I extract from this JSON?

Tags: ruby, json

I'm trying to extract data from this JSON, however when I type [0], it returns '{' & if I type ["tweets0"], I get nothing. Am I missing something really obvious?

I'm using Ruby & the MultiJson gem, if that changes anything.

```
{
    "tweets0": [
        {
            "content": "Test1",
            "time": "2015/08/16 7:43 PM"
        }
    ],
    "tweets1": [
        {
            "content": "Test2",
            "time": "2015/08/16 7:44 PM"
        }
    ],
    "tweets2": [
        {
            "content": "Test3",
            "time": "2015/08/16 7:44 PM"
        }
    ],
    "tweets3": [
        {
            "content": "Test3",
            "time": "2015/08/16 7:46 PM"
        }
    ],
    "tweets4": [
        {
            "content": "Test",
            "time": "2015/08/16 7:45 PM"
        }
    ],
    "tweets5": [
        {
            "content": "3",
            "time": "2015/08/16 7:48 PM"
        }
    ],
    "tweets6": [
        {
            "content": "3",
            "time": "2015/08/16 7:48 PM"
        }
    ],
    "tweets7": [
        {
            "content": "3213",
            "time": "2015/08/16 7:49 PM"
        }
    ],
    "tweets8": [
        {
            "content": "3213",
            "time": "2015/08/16 7:49 PM"
        }
    ],
    "tweets9": [
        {
            "content": "23",
            "time": "2015/08/16 7:50 PM"
        }
    ],
    "tweets10": [
        {
            "content": "23",
            "time": "2015/08/16 7:49 PM"
        }
    ],
    "tweets11": [
        {
            "content": "3",
            "time": "2015/08/16 7:53 PM"
        }
    ],
    "tweets12": [
        {
            "content": "34",
            "time": "2015/08/16 7:53 PM"
        }
    ],
    "tweets13": [
        {
            "content": "25",
            "time": "2015/08/16 7:53 PM"
        }
    ],
    "tweets14": [
        {
            "content": "right",
            "time": "2015/08/16 7:52 PM"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you post a snippet of the code you are using to load and access the data?

Answer (score 2):

If [0] returns '{', than that suggests to me that Ruby isn't treating your JSON as a JSON object, but as a string.

Maybe you need to `.load()` your JSON first?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the standard `json` library built into Ruby?

```
require 'json'
a = JSON.parse(your_json_data)
a["tweets0"] #=> [{"content"=>"Test1", "time"=>"2015/08/16 7:43 PM"}]
```

Comment: Because the stdlib's `json` library is implemented using pure ruby, thus is slow. `multi_json` tries to use `oj`, and fallbacks to `yajl`, then to `json`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have loaded your data with MultiJson

```
> require 'multi_json'
> json = MultiJson.load('{"tweets0": [{"content": "Test1","time": "2015/08/16 7:43 PM"}]}')
=> {"tweets0"=>[{"content"=>"Test1", "time"=>"2015/08/16 7:43 PM"}]}
```

Then you can access a Hash element via name:

```
> json['tweets0']
=>[{"content"=>"Test1", "time"=>"2015/08/16 7:43 PM"}]
```

To access elements of the array:

```
> json['tweets0'].first
=> {"content"=>"Test1", "time"=>"2015/08/16 7:43 PM"}
```